# socket.io MEAN stack ( why l can't connect to event ?)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, socket.io

**Server side:**

app.js

```
let express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http').Server(app);
    io = require('socket.io')(http);
http.listen(port, function () {
  ...
});
io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
    socket.emit('some_event',{user : 'some_name'})
});
```

routes/index.js

```
let router = express.Router();
.....
router.get('/api/telegram/activation-code',user.isLoggedIn(),telegramActivation);
```

**Client Side :**

any_angular.component.ts

```
    import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
    ...
    ngOnInit(){
      let socket = io('/api/telegram/activation-code');
          socket.on('connection', (socket) =>{
            socket.on('some_event',(data) =>{
               console.log(data)
             })
          });
    }
```

I try to get some data from server side. But when I move to my */api/telegram/activation-code* route I don't receive a data. Who can explain to me where my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your back and front are in different namespaces. Try this in your node code

```
io.of('/api/telegram/activation-code').on('connection...
```

https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#custom-namespaces

Comment: I do smth like this in my code , but I have a same problem io.of('/api/telegram/activation-code').on('connection', (socket) =>{
    socket.emit('some_event',{user : 'some_name'})
});

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich Can you give a screenshot of ws connection with 'Frames' tab active?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your message. Could you explain me once more?What should I provide you?

Comment: Okay I'm really no expert with socket.io on a client but I don't think you should listen to 'connection' event there. Can you remove handler for 'connection' event on a client and just directly handle 'some_event'?